# During the usage of tradingview, I wrote my own jsapi, everything seems to work fine, until I use onHistorycallback and pass in my data, it prompts me

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase')
[image: img1]
[image: img2]

I tried to parse the error code but I failed, the first time I used it.the direction of the attempt may need to be reminded

[image: img3]

Comment: Please copy and paste the code in to the question. Images of code are not helpful

Comment: You are trying to call toLowerCase on some variable you expect to be a string. The variable is undefined hence the error.

Comment: Please check this guide on [How to ask Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)